# How to setup Android Firebase Notification in Manifest?

Tags: android, firebase, manifest, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to setup Firebase notifications. I did changes in app level and root level build.gradle. But still, its giving me error in Manifest for MyFirebaseMessagingService. Error is Unresolved Class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".s" />
    <activity android:name=".im" />
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".sactivity" />
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity
        android:name=".ScrollingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_scrolling"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Is MyFirebaseMessaginService actually a class?

Comment: Just a tip, upgrade to Android Studio 2.2; when upgraded if you go to Tools>Firebase you can set up any app without having to add any classes or dependencies as it will add it itself. Just go to Tools>Firebase, select notifications from the window that popped up. Then follow everything they say there.

Comment: No. I followed the tutorial on https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience

Comment: They don't yet include the fact about the Firebase plugin. I suggest upgrading and using it

Comment: @AbAppletic: while I like that you're promoting the new Firebase Assistant in Android Studio 2.2, I have no reason to believe that it'll make difference to this process? Have you seen a case where coolamz's problem occurs that was problem occurs and it was solved with the new assistant? If so, can you share details of that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm not saying it'll solve his problem as it adds no services, I'm just saying it could save him time next time he's setting up an app with Firebase.

Comment: I recoded the activity and updated to Android Studio 2.2. They've made it very simple. Thanks  AbAppletic, Frank van Puffelen and AbAppletic for your support!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the Android Manifest file can't locate the `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class. I'd suggest you to put the fully qualified package name of the class. See example below:

```
    <service android:name="com.android.notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Thank you i forget about it :(

Answer (score 0):

Oh! you haven't create any java class here, lets just get around it since |service| is instantiated to true on default.You should make `android:enabled="false",`i think this should work. see detail code below.

```
<service  android:enabled="false" android:name="MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <service android:name="com.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingServices">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="com.fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIdServices">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```